# Errors Inserting commas to separate spark sql query result

Tags: apache-spark-sql, databricks

I am trying to write some SQL queries on databricks that would produce outputs with commas.
The code below successfully produced the output I wanted, but not with commas.

```
%sql
SELECT Country, CONCAT('£ ',TRIM(ROUND(SUM(Quantity * UnitPrice), 2))) as Country_sales
FROM ecommerce_new
GROUP BY Country
Order by SUM(Quantity * UnitPrice) Desc
```

Output

[image]

The idea is to produce something similar to the Country_sales column, where the values are separated with commas. I tried to use the TO_CHAR method with '9G999G999', but I kept getting errors.

```
Country           Country_sales
United Kingdom   £ 7,299,517.53
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`format_number` function](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/functions/format_number.html) to do such formatting:

```sql
SELECT format_number(12332.123456, '£ ,###.-')
```